# Reading String and Ints on the same file line

Tags: java, arrays, string, vector, parseint

Hello I have a function that reads int's separated by whitespace (0 1 0 2 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 1) and inserts position by position in a vector.
This is working fine.

```
    public void readTemplate() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    
    File templateFile = new File ("C:\\Temp\\templateFile.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(templateFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    
    String row;
    
    int j=0;
    
    while((row = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] strings = row.split(" ");
        for (String str : strings) {
             Integer foo = Integer.parseInt(str);
             vectorTemplate[j] = foo;
             j++;
        }
            
            }
    br.close();
    fr.close();
    System.out.println("TEMPLATE FILE SUCCESFULY OPENED");
}
```

Now I have a new need which is to read a string on the same line.

Thinking this is the name of a bettor and their bets:

JOHN 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 0

I have a Bet type class, where I need to save the name as String and the other elements in a bet vector of this user.

I don't know how to read this first information as a string to save in my variable name and the rest of the line normally as a vector.

I have tried some alternatives but I always run into java.lang.NumberFormatException

I believe the error is in the line I left bold (            **totalBets[j].setName(str);**
)

```
public void betsReads() throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
    
    File betsFile = new File ("C:\\Temp\\bets.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(betsFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) { 
    
    String row;
      
    while((row= br.readLine()) != null) {
        totalBets[j] = new Bet();
        String[] strings = row.split(" ");
        for (String str : strings) {
            **totalBets[j].setName(str);**
            for(int i = 0; i < bets.vectorBets.length; i++) { 
             Integer foo = Integer.parseInt(str);
             totalBets[j].vectorBers[i] = foo;
            }
             j++;
        }
            
            }
            
            }
    br.close();
    fr.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `String` in the array of tokens is the name. Every value after that is a bet. Also, use `try-with-Resources` instead of explicitly closing. Like,

```
public void betsReads() throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
    File betsFile = new File("C:\\Temp\\bets.txt");
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(betsFile);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        String row;
        int j = 0;
        while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) {
            totalBets[j] = new Bet();
            String[] strings = row.split("\\s+");
            totalBets[j].setName(strings[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
                int foo = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
                totalBets[j].vectorBers[i - 1] = foo;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect my friend!

Congratulations for helping the community and for didactics, with your few lines I understood what should be done.

Thank you again!